# Cannot enter backslash on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

On my Windows 7 laptop, I have recently encountered a strange problem: The key for the backslash does not work. I use a German keyboard, where the backslash is entered using one of:

- Strg (Ctrl) + Alt + ß ("Sharp S")
- AltGr + ß

Both do not work. I can enter other characters using these keys without problem:

- ß
- ?: Shift + ß
- @: AltGr + Q / Strg + Alt + Q

So the keys are not broken. It already did work, I have been using the laptop irregularly for quite some time and regularly for school since September.

What could the problem be? How can I fix it?

Comment: I found a forum thread about it, there was only a recommendation for a workaround (use Windows Unicode entry Alt+092), but not a satisfying solution. German thread: http://www.winfuture-forum.de/index.php?showtopic=62452

Comment: You do have `Language: German` AND `Keyboard: German` selected in keyboard layout? Like [this](http://i.imgur.com/OdpooyN.png)? What is actually outputted when you do `AltGr + ß`?

Comment: Nothing is outputted - it is silently ignored.

Comment: And I do have German Language AND keyboard (just German/Austria, not German/Germany, but it should not be a difference): https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=250525041772474&l=dde14e3232

Comment: Mmm, if it does not output anything it might be the key is being 'eaten' by another app. Could you terminate all apps in the system-tray. Also, what is the make/model of the laptop? Another, less satisfying option, would be to remap another key with AutoHotkey. It's better than `Alt+92` but not ideal. Did you try the key-combo in Safe Mode? Also, try setting a different keyboard/language deleting the one you have. After that add the German back and set it again as default. It might be the keyboard-layout file is corrupt.

Comment: You were right. I had a shortcut in Skype to answer a call with Ctrl + Alt + ß. I changed it, and now it works. Why does it eat AltGr + ß, though?

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+ß` is mapped to the **same key** as `AltGr+ß` **by the OS**, so both keys work the same and both keys will work as "answering a call in Skype". The default for answering a call in Skype was `Alt+PgUp`. So change it back to that (or something else) and you have your `AltGr+ß` back.